# Why, when we use the logarithmic function, weigh less to overfit?

Tags: neural-networks, overfitting

Why, when we use the logarithmic function, weigh less to overfit, or why I create less local logarithmic errors, they wanted an answer with proof.

Comment: This is very unclear; could you try expanding it somewhat?   Also, if it's homework, please add the "self-study" tag, and tell us more explicitly what you understand and what you don't understand.